# What does this line of perl mean/do?

Tags: perl

The code I'm curious about:

```
my @sorted=sort { $b->[0] <=> $a->[0] } @unsorted
```

My guess is that `@sorted` is the sorted `@unsorted` array.

What does `<=>` mean?  My guess is that the array is an array of arrays, so it's comparing the first items of every pair of arrays.
I can't find `<=>` in the perl doc.

Comment: [Docs for spaceship](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators). [Docs for `sort`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html).

Answer (score 8):

Like all operators, `<=>` (sometimes known as the spaceship operator) is documented in [`perldoc perlop`](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Equality-Operators):

> Binary `<=>` returns -1, 0, or 1 depending on whether the left argument is numerically less than, equal to, or greater than the right argument. If your platform supports `NaN`'s (not-a-numbers) as numeric values, using them with `<=>` returns undef.

The code sorts an array of references to arrays by the first element of each sub-array in numerically descending order.

See also: [`perldoc -f sort`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/sort), [`perldoc perlreftut`](https://perldoc.pl/perlreftut)

Comment: Some operators are only documented in [perlsecret](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsecret).

Comment: @mob Those aren't real operators though; they are just combinations of other operators, all documented in perlop.

Answer (score 2):

The `<=>` is the [spaceship operator](https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-operators/#Comparison_operators_for_numbers) (because of how it looks). It's used to compare it arguments (on the left and on the right) numerically and return a value less than 0 if left is smaller than right, 0 if they are equal, or greater than zero if the right side is smaller than the left.

The [sort](https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-sort/) function can take e.g., a block of code (the part in curly braces) that defines how to sort the elements of `@unsorted`, and the sorted result is stored in `@sorted`.